# How to process multiple Jpeg images in R

Tags: r

I just started using RStudio, as the available package to analyze my images is in R. I just want to analyze some 50 images which are stored in a folder. How can I read each image (by forming a loop), perform some operation on each image and save the output (my output is a list) as a vector?

**UPDATE:**

I just wrote a piece of code which is as following:

```
folder <- "F:/F_diff/1_d/glass/New folder/"      # path to folder that holds multiple .jpg files
file_list <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.jpg") # create list of all .jpg files in folder

for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  assign(file_list[i],   
     #read image
     im2 <- readImage(paste(folder, file_list[i], sep=''))

     #analyze each image
     B <- matrix(im2,nrow=808,ncol=610,byrow=FALSE, dimnames=NULL)
     Haarimtest <- TOS2D(B, smooth = FALSE, nsamples = 100)
     summary(Haarimtest)

 )}
```

I am getting the following errors:

> Error: unexpected symbol in:
>   "         #analyze each image
>            B"
>            Haarimtest <- TOS2D(B, smooth = FALSE, nsamples = 100)
>   Error in base::log2(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>            summary(Haarimtest)
>   Error in summary(Haarimtest) : object 'Haarimtest' not found
>
> )}
>   Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"

**UPDATE 2**

After some tinkering with the code and lot of searching, I was able to run it.
The code first imports all 30 .tif images of size 64x64 pixels from a folder and perform some image analysis on each image
The updated code is as follows:

```
> library(tiff) 
  library(LS2W) 
  library(LS2Wstat)
> # path to folder that holds multiple .tif files 
  path <- "C:/Users/Metaheuristics/Documents/MATLAB/diff_64 x64/2D/" 
> # create list of all .tif files in folder 
  files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.tif") 
> 
> #import all files  
  for(file in files) {   
  perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")   
  assign(
> gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
> B<-readTIFF(paste(path,file,sep="")))
> 
  #perform image analysis on individual images   
  Haarimtest <- TOS2D(B, smooth = FALSE, nsamples = 100)            
  summary(Haarimtest)   
  }
```

Just one problem, I am not being able to save the result.

Comment: If you know how to read one image file then you can do similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r

Comment: see these two posts [looping through all files in directory in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958516/looping-through-all-files-in-directory-in-r-applying-multiple-commands) and [how to read jpeg in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283447/how-to-read-jpeg-in-r-2-15)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take a look at how questions should be asked : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  It's an interesting question, but without at least an idea about what code you tried and which package you use for analyzing the image, it's impossible to answer satisfactory.

Comment: I am using the LS2Wstat package (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/LS2Wstat/versions/2.0-3) which is a multiscale test for spatial stationarity for textured images. these textured images are laser speckle fields obtained from optical experiments.

Comment: The documentation says that `TOS2D()` function takes an image as one of the arguments whereas you are providing a matrix `B`, I would suggest that you pass `im2` as argument instead of `B`

Comment: HI,
For a single image of size 808x610, the following code works just fine, (here im2 is a numeric image array, and I convert it to a matrix B)

 im2 <- load.image("F:/F_diff/1_d/glass/1.jpg")
B <- matrix(im2,nrow=808,ncol=610,byrow=FALSE, dimnames=NULL)
Haarimtest <- TOS2D(B, smooth = FALSE, nsamples = 100)
summary(Haarimtest)

Comment: replace the line ` assign(file_list[i],  im2 <- readImage(paste(folder, file_list[i], sep=''))` with ` im2 <- readImage(paste(folder, file_list[i], sep=''))`, I don't think you need `assign` here

Comment: Run `lapply` over a vector of the file names you construct instead of using a `for` loop, and remove the last line of the loop (`summary(Haarimtest)`), and you'll get a list comprising the results of the calls to `TOS2D`. Then you can inspect or further process or whatever those results one by one or with additional calls to `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems like its been like 2 years since this question. I had a similar problem and found the solution to it.

before your for loop,
add: `df <- NULL`
and after you line in:

```
Haarimtest <- TOS2D(B, smooth = FALSE, nsamples = 100)
```

just add (within for loop)

```
df<-rbind(df,data.frame(file,Haarimtest))
```